# Inherited memory

Tags: alien-franchise, xenomorph

As we know, aliens had inherited memory as seen in this review:

```
Ripley's genes are all right too: 
They allow her reconstituted form to retain all her old memories, 
as if cookie dough could remember what a gingerbread man looked like.
— Roger Ebert's review of Alien Resurrection
```

Does each new generation of aliens get better in experience? What happens if they produce from a victim that is very intelligence (example: chestburster from Kasparov or Euler or Hawking)

Does the 10th generation queen have at least 10x the experience of the first queen? What about drone,runner and praetorians?

Comment: There are better examples of DNA-encoded memory in science fiction than this abomination of a sequel. Ask about them please.

Comment: I edited out the last paragraph, because it was unrelated to inherited memories. Now your question is more focused. It is still a bit too speculative in my opinion, though.